# Making paragraph stick to bottom with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have some blocks on a website which look like this:

[image]

There are three blocks next to eachother. Now the problem here is that title can be one line of length, like in the image, to 4 lines of length. Depending on the length of the title, I successfully alter the content, so that the content stays within the block and doesn't overflow.

However, the buttons in all three blocks needs to be on the same height, no matter how long the content and the title are. I thought that I could make them sticky to the bottom of the block, so I already gave the parent a `position: relative` and the child a `position: absolute`, but they just don't want to stick to the bottom, they still appeared on different heights. I also fooled around with `display: flex` and `position: fixed`, but I couldn't manage to make this work.

Of course, I could manage the position of the blocks with jQuery, depending on the height of the title or something like that, but I really want to use as less Javascript as possible, because of performance.

The HTML for every block is:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <div class="post-header">
        <span class="cat"><a href="some-url" title="some-title">Here goes the category</a></span>
        <h2><a href="some-url">Here goes the title</a></h2>
        <span class="date">1 january 1970</span>
    </div>

    <div class="post-entry">
        <p>This is the content of the post</p>
        <p><a href="some-url" class="more-link"><span class="more-button">Read more link</span></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could post the CSS also, but that doesn't contain more than just some background properties, paddings for the text, etc.

So what I need is no matter how long the title or the content is, the button always needs to be sticky to the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They probably ARE sticky to the bottom, but if the container they're in is flexible in height (which it seems it needs to be), they will be at different heights, unless you set a specific min-height / max-height on all containers.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie do you mean the class `post-entry` as the container? Because that's the parent element of the button (or p-tag in this case). The blocks itself already have a min-height.

Comment: No, I mean the container that has `position: relative;`, since that is what the `position: absolute;` will render against. If you have put `position: relative;` on the `post-entry`, then I suggest changing that to the outer container, perhaps. And a min-height will only work alone if the content is always less than the min-height. If the content exceeds the min-height on one container, but not on the others, there will be differences. Could you perhaps set up a code-snippet with a complete set of HTML and CSS (for this problem) so we can see the containers, and the problem you're having?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I just fixed it! You were right, I was setting `position: relative` to `post-entry`, but it had to be `post-content` for it to work. Of course, it will take the height of the block if I do that, instead of the height of the content inside the block. Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, this is why posting CSS can be important. I misunderstood a bit, and thought you had put the CSS on the outer container (the `post-content`) - had I known that it was on the immediate parent, the `post-entry`, this would have been solved much faster ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (after discussing in the comments) is that the `position: relative;` was set on `post-entry`, instead of the outer container `post-content`. Changing that will fix the problem, as long as the other rules are set correctly.